# static objects in a factory pattern (C++) and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have written the following code and have some questions about the memory allocation and its use in a multi-threading environment.

The class `ClsFactory` returns static objects based on the `id` (not illustrated).

1. How can I free memory allocated to this static object before the program termination? If I get it right, using `std::auto_ptr`, would pass on the ownership to the `auto_ptr` in `main` .. I am trying to avoid that.
2. Given that I can create all necessary singletons ( e.g. `Cls` instance ) at the beginning of program , before spawning the threads, would there be any issue with use of the singletons here?

In short I want to use a factory to get singletons created before spawning the threads, then delete the singletons once the parallel tasks are done.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I am reading stuff about dependency injection in this forum. If there is a better design for the code I am illustrating below, I would appreciate a code sample.

```
class Cls {
public:
    Cls(){};
    ~Cls(){};
    void doSomething();
};

class ClsFactory {
private:
    static Cls* c;
    //static ClsChild1 c1;
public:
    static Cls* make(int id);
    //static Cls* makeChild1();
};

void Cls::doSomething(){
    cout<<"In Cls::doSomething()"<<endl;
}

Cls* ClsFactory::c  = NULL;

Cls* ClsFactory::make(int id){
    // arg id not yet used... 
    cout<<"Inside ClsFactory::make"<<endl;\
    if(c == NULL){
        c = new Cls();
    }       
    return c;
}


int main(){
    Cls* c;
    int id = 100;
    c = ClsFactory::make(id);
    c->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first point, you shouldn't free it. Not unless you need to free it while the program is running. It will be free automatically by the system when the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue with deleting the singletons, if you want to free space for more processing after the threads are done. Just be sure that all the threads have joined the main before doing so.